# How can I create an ImmutableList as a member variable?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I need to create an `ImmutableList` as a member variable.

Here's what I tried:

```
  private List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
  private ImmutableList<String> stringList2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(stringList);
```

This fails to compile with the error:

```
FakeRemoteDataStore.java:59: error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to ImmutableList<String>
  private ImmutableList<String> stringList2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(stringList);
                                                                          ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>unmodifiableList(List<? extends T>)
```

How can I create an `ImmutableList` as a member variable?

Comment: `ImmutableList` is a separate type and won't be compatible to what `java.util.Collections` is returning. Try `stringList2 = ImmutableList.copyOf(stringList)`.

Comment: What is `ImmutableList`? must be something out of Java SE.

Answer (score 1):

[`ImmutableList`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) is part of Guava, so you can just do:

```
private ImmutableList<String> stringList = ImmutableList.of("a", "b", "c");
```

Comment: Or you can do what [YCF_L said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014513/how-can-i-create-an-immutablelist-as-a-member-variable#comment113198389_64014513), and not use third-party library at all.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick responses. I'm editing an existing codebase and wasn't aware that it was using Guava classes. Searching for "create an ImmutableList in Java" reveals answers which are about "immutable lists" rather than the specific Guava class `ImmutableList`, hence my confusion. Hopefully this answer will help others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `copyOf` function from `ImmutableList`

```
ImmutableList<String> stringList2 = ImmutableList.copyOf(stringList);
```

Comment: True, but `stringList` is an unnecessary intermediate variable.

Comment: Agreed, we can avoid this intermediate variable. We have two variations of the answers here, if someone wants to create a new list he can refer the above answer and if someone already has a list then he can use this answer.